# Java convert a pdf returned as Rest API response to text

Tags: java, rest, java-8, inputstream, apache-tika

I have to consume as rest api API(/getconstomerList) from my java code that returns a pdf file.
I need to read the PDF file and convert it to String.

I tried doing this with tika

```
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(10 * 1024 * 1024);
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
URL url = new URL("http://" + hostName + uri);
BufferedInputStream inputstream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
parser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata, pcontext);
return handler.toString();
```

But this code keep returning me empty response, I am not sure what is wrong or if there is any other way to do this. Please help.

Comment: Does the code work if you take out the download part and feed the same PDF from a local file into it? There may be redirects and such involved, better download the PDF into memory (or temporary file) first before handing it to Tika.

Comment: Yes the code works with local pdf, I tested it with the same that's being provided with the rest response. 
I am new with handling file as rest response, can try saving it locally first.

Answer (score 1):

For HTTP calls, I would recommend [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) library. You can easily setup/configure by providing an `interface` containing API methods. One of those methods would return the `Call<ResponseBody>` from which get the `ResponseBody` and using it you can get the `InputStream`. Using it, you can convert the stream to file and do what you would like to do with it. Below is a sample code.

```
String downloadFileAndReadAsString(ResponseBody responseBody, Path filePath) {
    try (InputStream inputStream = responseBody.byteStream()) {
        Path downloadedFilePath = Files.copy(inputStream, filePath, 
StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
return new String(Files.readAllBytes(downloadedFilePath));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.